# I have installed Jdk 16 in ubuntu 20.04.i have set up the path but when i run a program in eclipse, i see launch error

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-20.04, java-16

Error description :

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'TestProject'.
For input string: "G" under radix 16

Comment: Radix 16 goes only to F. So the TestProject probably contains unit test error or such. Would need more info on the error. Start with your own first Hello World.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.